# How can I show timestamp in natural date format in minibuffer?

Tags: key-bindings, time-date

I am working quite a lot with Unix timestamps. I installed the `ts` package, but I am not able to create a key-binding to show the conversion of a timestamp to natural date format.

I would like to be able to show the natural day of a marked timestamp. Is it possible to show in the minibuffer? Or at cursor point?. I don't want to replace or timestamp or insert in the current buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple-minded implementation that tries to detect the Unix timestamp at point. Assuming it finds one, it converts it to a human-readable date and prints it in the echo area, in the format specified by `ts-default-format` (which is defined in the `ts` package):

```el
(require 'ts)

(defun ndk/ts-at-point ()
  (unless (looking-at "[0-9.]")
    nil)
  (let ((origin (point))
        beg end)
    (save-excursion
      (setq beg (+ origin (skip-chars-backward "0123456789."))))
    (save-excursion
      (setq end (+ origin (skip-chars-forward "0123456789."))))
    (list beg end)))

(defun ndk/show-date-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((r (ndk/ts-at-point))
         (beg (nth 0 r))
         (end (nth 1 r))
         (unix_ts (buffer-substring beg end)))
    (message (ts-format (make-ts :unix (float (read unix_ts)))))))
```

The first function scans backwards and forwards trying to find the beginning and end of the timestamp that `point` is on. It's a bit fragile and simplistic and can be fooled easily, but it should  do the job if you don't push it too far.

It is called by `ndk/show-date-at-point` to get the limits, which then reads that portion of the buffer, tries to convert it to a float and, if it succeeds, it assumes it's a Unix timestamp and converts it to a human-readable date, which is then echoed in the echo area with `message`.

To use it, put your cursor on a timestamp and say `M-x ndk/show-date-at-point`.
Or bind it to a key to make it easy to call:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") #'ndk/show-date-at-point)
```

`C-c d` is supposed to be unused by packages so that users can use it for their own purposes, but if you happen to use it already, choose another `C-c <letter>` binding.

Comment: Is working perfectly. I just need to use `global-set-key` instead of `global-define-key`)

Comment: Fixed - thanks for pointing it out.